# Magento2 : How to get active payment methods list store wise

Tags: magento2, payment, stores, methods

I want to get all active payment method list store wise.

I have two store

-- store indstore

-- store usstore

And i have set payment methods for only **indstore** 
and if i try to get all active methods ,it returns from default store settings
and from default settings payment methods are disable.

if i enable from default settings than i got all payment methods.

Does anyone know how i can get methods store wise?

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\System\Methods.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\System;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Model\Config;
class Methods implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $paymentmodelconfig;

    public function __construct(Config $paymentmodelconfig, ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        $this->paymentmodelconfig = $paymentmodelconfig;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $payments = $this->paymentmodelconfig->getActiveMethods();

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $methodList = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,1);

            foreach ($methodList as $code => $_method) {
                $active_status = "";
                $title = "";
                if (isset($_method['active']))
                {
                    if ($_method['active'] == 1)
                    {
                        if (isset($_method['title']))
                        {
                            $title = $_method['title'];
                            $logger->info($title);
                        }
                    }
                }
                 $methods = array();
                 return $methods;
        }
    }
}
```

> > Output IN Log File

2019-12-24T05:55:20+00:00 INFO (6): Check / Money order

> Paypal is also active but i am getting only check/money order

Comment: Thanks @RohanHapani But using above link i got payment method as per default settings,but i want store wise

Comment: You can just set it as : $this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,'store_code');

Comment: Let me know if you have still confusion about that.

Comment: @RohanHapani i have tried as per you suggest but still getting same output , i have paypal payment method enable for only storeind but i m not gettting that payment method

Comment: Update your full code in question which you have tried.

Comment: @RohanHapani i have checked by enabling Check / Money order method on storeind and now i am getting that method , so why i am not getting paypal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102527/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-sanjay-shiyal).

Comment: Check this link : https://www.rohanhapani.com/list-of-payment-methods-using-command-line-in-magento-2/

Comment: yes i have checked same things from using that code but only i am not getting paypal method

Comment: @SanjayShiyal Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/302345/57334

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class ABC{
    protected $paymentMethodList;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Model\PaymentMethodList $paymentMethodList
    ) {
        $this->paymentMethodList = $paymentMethodList;
    }

    public function getmethods()
    {
        $storeId = 'your store id';
        $this->paymentMethodList->getActiveList($storeId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Padhiyar Gaurang Working Great !!!

Comment: @SanjayShiyal felling good that it helps!! Cheers

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359058/magento2-4-2-how-to-display-only-those-payment-method-options-in-filter-in-sale
kindly can you check this question

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use \Magento\Payment\Model\Config;

class Paymentmethod extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject 
    implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $_paymentModelConfig;

    /**
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $appConfigScopeConfigInterface
     * @param Config               $paymentModelConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $appConfigScopeConfigInterface,
        Config $paymentModelConfig
    ) {

        $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface = $appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
        $this->_paymentModelConfig = $paymentModelConfig;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $payments = $this->_paymentModelConfig->getActiveMethods();
        $methods = array();
        foreach ($payments as $paymentCode => $paymentModel) {
            $paymentTitle = $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface
                ->getValue('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
            $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
                'label' => $paymentTitle,
                'value' => $paymentCode
            );
        }
        return $methods;
    }
}
```

Here `$_appConfigScopeConfigInterface` is an object of `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` class.

`$_paymentModelConfig` is an object of `Magento\Payment\Model\Config` class.

and in `toOptionArray()` function we use a method: `getActiveMethods()` which returns model of all the active methods.

In return array we have all payment methods with their code and title.